# Пропадают русские имена файлов в отправляемом письме (SMTP)

Tags: python, smtp, smtplib

Код рабочий, отправляю им PDF файлы с mail.ru на yandex/gmail... **Почему при отправке тех же файлов c mail.ru на mail.ru они приходят как "Untitled.bin"?** Если изменить расширение в скачанных файлах, они читаются.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.ru', 465)
server.login(fromaddr, mypass)

def send_mail(toaddr, subjectText, bodyText, filesToAttach=[]):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = subjectText
    body = bodyText
    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

    files=filesToAttach
    for f in files or []:
        with open(f, "rb") as fil:
            part = MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Name=basename(f)
            )

        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
        msg.attach(part)

    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

server.quit()
```

Comment: В имени файла русских букв случайно нет?

Comment: Есть. Проверил сейчас, латиницей всё приходит. Единственный выход - убирать русские буквы?

Comment: Нет, просто экранировать правильно (правда, я забыл как)

Comment: Ок, буду искать. Спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13646202/send-email-to-exchange-with-attachment-in-russian-file-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заголовки в SMTP должны содержать только ASCII-символы. Так исторически сложилось: SMTP появился в те времена, когда ни Unicode, ни даже кодировок CP866 и CP1251 даже в проекте не было (какой уж там юникод — тогда даже [проблемы с восьмибитными символами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean) были).

Чтобы как-то поддержать юникод и прочие кодировки, начали изобретать разнообразные костыли, такие как [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) или [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231), при которых имя файла (например, `файл.txt`) будет закодировано в `Content-Disposition` только ASCII-символами примерно так:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?UTF-8?B?0YTQsNC50LsudHh0?="
```

или так:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB.txt
```

На наше счастье, в питоне уже встроена поддержка RFC 2231, просто нужно использовать `MIMEApplication` немножко по-другому:

```
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
# ...
part = MIMEApplication(b'hello', Name='файл.txt')
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='файл.txt')
print(part)
```

---

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Name*=utf-8''%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB.txt
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB.txt

aGVsbG8=
```